# Python: match elements from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

After parsing of csv file, i am getting this list from one of the rows:

```
['', 'value1', '346.897', '', 'value2', '202.306', 'value3', '136.880', 'value4', '7.711', '']
```

as a result, I need to get:

```
{
    'value1': 346.897,
    'value2': 202.306,
    ...
}
```

Does anyone know how to make it beautiful? not using indexes.

Now, I remove all empty string from the list and then take `[0]` element like `key` and `[1]` like `value` and etc.

```
Variables :value1 # ... - are dynamic
```

Comment: beautiful, as in `zipping`? ;)

Comment: you can import the `csv` module and just use that for the parsing. the result you would like to have can easily be generated like that.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I have really bad csv. All rows very different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
s = ['', 'value1', '346.897', '', 'value2', '202.306', 'value3', '136.880', 'value4', '7.711', '']
s = list(filter(None, s))        # fastest way to remove the empty strs        
zipped = zip(s[0::2], s[1::2])   # zip them   

print({k:v for k,v in dict(zipped).items()})
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'value1': '346.897', 'value2': '202.306', 'value3': '136.880', 'value4': '7.711'}
```

**Shorter-version**:

```
s = list(filter(None, s))
print(dict(zip(s[0::2], s[1::2])))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'value1': '346.897', 'value2': '202.306', 'value3': '136.880', 'value4': '7.711'}
```

[pyFiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/ac080ae9-fb99-4b3c-ad78-21bd4385c152/?i=true)

Comment: How does the shorter-version work? Why doesnt it include the swiched key-value pairs, like: `'346.897': 'value2'` ?

Comment: @Lucas It does, `zip()` expects iterables, provided `s` with the complete list and `s[1:]` with the list skipping the first elem, converting to to dict removes the duplicate keys: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip

Comment: I see, however I just ran It an the dict will still contain the acctual values for keys, afterall this can be expected, as they are no duplicates.

Comment: @Lucas which Python version are you on? It looks like it was breaking on 2.x, but the edited version should work just fine now. cheers

Comment: Well, I was on python 2.7, but indeed, now it should work!

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the empty elements from the list, divide the elements in to chunks of 2 and then use a dict comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
data = ['', 'value1', '346.897', '', 'value2', '202.306', 'value3', '136.880', 'value4', '7.711', '']

data = [i for i in data if i]   #Clean data
data = [data[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)]   #Divide list elements to chunks of 2
result = {k: v for k, v in data}    #dict comprehension 
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'value1': '346.897',
 'value2': '202.306',
 'value3': '136.880',
 'value4': '7.711'}
```

Comment: you can omit line 3 and rewrite line 4 as `result = [ { u: v } for u,v in zip( *[ iter( data ) ] * 2 ) ]
`

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to first get rid of the empty strings and then to convert this into a dictionary, knowing that you need to take a step of 2 on the index to step from one pair (key, value) to the next:

```
L = ['', 'value1', '346.897', '', 'value2', '202.306', 'value3', '136.880', 'value4', '7.711', '']
L = [elt for elt in L if elt != '']
D = {L[k]:L[k+1] for k in range(0, len(L), 2)}
```

Output:

```
Out[8]: 
{'value1': '346.897',
 'value2': '202.306',
 'value3': '136.880',
 'value4': '7.711'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
input_list = ['', 'value1', '346.897', '', 'value2', '202.306', 'value3', '136.880', 'value4', '7.711', '']

# Filtering for empty strings
res = [item for item in input_list if item != ""]

# Making pairs of list items
pairs = zip(res[::2], res[1::2])


res_dict = dict(pairs)

print (res_dict)
```

Outputting:

```
{'value1': '346.897', 'value2': '202.306', 'value3': '136.880', 'value4': '7.711'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about the adjacent `key`, `value` pair in the list. You could just make an `iterator` from that `list` and make a `dict` out of it like,

```
>>> data
['', 'value1', '346.897', '', 'value2', '202.306', 'value3', '136.880', 'value4', '7.711', '']
>>> data_ = [x for x in data if x] # clean the data
>>> d = iter(data_) # make an iterator
>>> {x: next(d) for x in d}
{'value4': '7.711', 'value3': '136.880', 'value2': '202.306', 'value1': '346.897'}
```